# Master of Many Styles and feat prerequisites

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monk, fighting-style

> [Master of Many Styles](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/master-of-many-styles/)
>
> At 1st level, 2nd level, and every four levels thereafter, a master of
>   many styles may select a bonus style feat or the Elemental Fist feat.
>   **He does not need to meet the prerequisites of that feat**, except the
>   Elemental Fist feat.

Does this mean that a MoMS could take a style feat later in the feat chain and make use of it (i.e. enter the associated style), without getting the first feat in the chain? For example, could I get and use [Crane Wing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-wing-combat) and/or [Crane Riposte](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-riposte-combat/) without ever acquiring [Crane Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-style-combat-style)?

Perhaps I've misunderstood the Master of Many Styles text, and "bonus style feat" refers only to the first feat in the style feat chain. If so, then it's not clearly worded as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style feats are feats that include the word "Style" in paretheses after the feat name (Ultimate Combat, pg. 76).

In the examples you provided, Crane Style has this style trait, but Crane Wing and Crane Riposte do not. Therefore, a Master of Many Styles could select Crane Style as a bonus feat without meeting the other prerequisites as a bonus feat, but could not select either Crane Wing or Crane Riposte.

As far as the clarity of the Master of Many Styles ability, it's just a question of knowing what a style feat is. This is spelled out cleanly in the original source:

> The type or types a feat belongs to appear in parentheses after the feat
>   name.

This is the same as other feat types. For example, teamwork feats always have the word "teamwork" in parentheses and combat feats always have the word "combat" in parentheses.

Comment: So [this table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/) that lists, for example, the feats Crane Wing and Crane Riposte as style feats is wrong? (If it is, that information should be included in this answer.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan At the very least, this site is inconsistent. That summary table says Crane Riposte is a style feat, but if you click that link to see the details Crane Riposte doesn't include the style type. I'll trace it back to Ultimate Combat to see what the original source says.

Comment: Confirmed. In Ultimate Combat (pg.93) the Crane Riposte and Crane Wing feats do not have the style type.

Comment: That certainly steamlines the use of MoMS wildcards. Good to know.

Comment: It may help to look at the first Feat as *the* style Feat, and the others as combat Feats that just alter the style. That seems to be the intent.